# Evaluating the infinite sum $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{2r^2 +3r+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, summation

How do I evaluate :

> $\lim_{n \to \infty}\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^n\left(\dfrac{1}{2r^2 +3r+1}\right)$

I tried sandwhich theorem and even wrote down some terms to see any particular pattern but these methods didn't help.

The thing to be summed can also be written as:

$2(\frac 1 {1+2r}- \frac1{2(r+1)})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{r\ge 0}\frac{1}{(r+1)(2r+1)}=2\sum_{r\ge 0}(\frac{1}{2r+1}-\frac{1}{2r+2})=2(1-\frac{1}{2}+\cdots)=2\ln 2=\ln 4$$

Comment: How did you get 2 ln2 in the last step?

Comment: @Abcd Famously $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$ if $|x|\le 1$.

Comment: @J.G. Not true for $x=-1$

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do it without series though.

Comment: @Adam Actually, it is; it's just that both sides end up being $-\infty$.

Comment: @J.G. normally $\ln(0)$ is undefined

Comment: @Abcd What do you mean, without series? Given what the answer is, you're bound to need a logarithmic Taylor series in any proof of this result.

Comment: @Adam That's not what I've ever seen.